# How to change focus from search bar to editor in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any keyboard shortcut to return cursor to highlighted search result **(to edit)** when using `Find` in `Sublime Text 3` ?

It would be awesome if there is a way to achieve this without having to use the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find what you want and then just hit **Esc** to edit it :)

```
Esc
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Try the answer by @freb (`ctrl+1`), which allows you to keep the search results highlighted while returning to the editor.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) doesn't allow you keep the search results highlighted when returning to the editor, since the search box closes.

To do this, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, which is the key binding for `focus_group, group: 0`.

Answer (score 1):

When it is highlighted, try hitting Control + D. The cursor should move to the highlighted selection.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/640241/selective-word-highlight-in-sublimetext) is a list of shortcuts pertaining to Sublime text search feature

Comment: That would only add the next match to selection, I need to return the cursor so I can edit it.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Targets the first highlight. Command + D moves to the next highlighted item, at least on Mac.

Comment: This is when using the search, try searching for something and change focus to editor from search bar.

Comment: I am. I search, it highlights the instance and I hit Control+D and the cursor moves from the search field to the end of the highlighted word.

Comment: That's odd, it just selects the next occurrence for me, focus still being on search bar.

Comment: Since I am on a mac, the shortcut might be different. Maybe try Control + D or Alt + D and see if either of those work.

Comment: Glad you got your answer